# Pass a Parameter and reference #div

Tags: html, vb.net, url

Is it possible to pass both a div id and a Parameter in a URL?

something along the lines of http://domain.com/Folder/default.aspx#ID?type=someparameter

Comment: I think it has to go the other way around: http://domain.com/Folder/default.aspx?type=someparameter#ID (everything after # is not sent to the server)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just put the `anchor` tag at the end,

**e.g**  `mypage.aspx?type=someparameter#ID`